# Jersey filters in non-servlet container

Tags: rest, jersey

I am running Jersey in a non-servlet container (Netty). For servlet-based containers, I can plug in a request filter using  :

```
<init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
         <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But how do I do this programmatically in my case ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completely non-servlet example:
Assuming you have created your request and/or response filter(s), you can add them to your startup code as follows: 
(Please note ApiInterceptor class is both a request and a response filter in this example)

```
    final URI BASE_URI = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9999).build();

    System.out.println("Investigating Api services...");        
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig(
        "path.to.your.resource.objects");

    System.out.println("Registering interceptors...");
    rc.getProperties().put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS, ApiInterceptor.class.getName());
    rc.getProperties().put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS, ApiInterceptor.class.getName());

    Debug.print("Starting grizzly...");
    GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);

    Debug.print("The app started @", BASE_URI.toString());
    Debug.print("Enjoy!");

    System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Netty, but for Grizzly its:

```
    .....

    webServer = new GrizzlyWebServer(getPort(8080), ".", true);

    // add Jersey resource servlet

    ServletAdapter jerseyAdapter = new ServletAdapter();
    jerseyAdapter.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.your.resources.package");
    jerseyAdapter.setContextPath("/");
    jerseyAdapter.setServletInstance(new ServletContainer());

    // add the Container filter 
    jerseyAdapter.addInitParameter(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS, GZIPContentEncodingFilter.class.getName());


    webServer.addGrizzlyAdapter(jerseyAdapter, new String[]{"/"});


    try {
        // start Grizzly embedded server //
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL at %sapplication.wadl", BASE_URI));
        webServer.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```